# Database error on insert through ajax in CodeIgniter

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, ajax, codeigniter

This is a weird error. I'm able to add records through Ajax, but the console shows this type of error:

```
Error Number: 1048

Column 'name' cannot be null

INSERT INTO `feedback` (`name`, `email`, `message`, `timecreated`) VALUES (NULL, NULL, NULL, 1407084933)

Filename: /var/www/html/storyline/models/feedback_model.php

Line Number: 10
```

Here is the structure:

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('#feedbacksubmit_button').click(function(){
        var name = $('#feedbackname').val();
        var email = $('#feedbackemail').val();
        var message = $('#feedbackmessage').val();
        if(message == ''){
            $('#feedbackmessage').next().show();
            return false;
        }
        var formvalues = {
            feedbackname  : name,
            feedbackemail  : email,
            feedbackmessage  : message,
        };
        $.ajax({
            type: "POST",
            url:  "<?php echo base_url();?>feedback/add",
            data: { values: formvalues },
            success: function(response) {
                alert("Thanks for your Feedback!");
            },
            error: function(error) {
                alert(error);
            }
        });
    });
});
```

`feedback.php` controller:

```
<?php

class Feedback extends CI_Controller {

    public function __construct() {
        parent::__construct();
        $this->load->model('feedback_model');
    }

    public function add() {
        $values = $this->input->post('values');
        $timecreated = time();
        $name = $values['feedbackname'];
        //echo $name;
        $data = array(
           'name' => $name,
           'email' => $values['feedbackemail'],
           'message' => $values['feedbackmessage'],
           'timecreated' => $timecreated,
        );
        $data['status'] = $this->feedback_model->new_feedback($data);
    }
}
```

`feedback_model.php`:

```
class Feedback_model extends CI_Model {

    public function __construct() {
        $this->load->database();
    }

    public function new_feedback($values) {  
      $this->db->insert('feedback', $values);
    }
}
```

**HTML form code:**

```
<form method="post">
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">Name</span>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your name" name="feedbackname" id="feedbackname" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <div class="input-group">
            <span class="input-group-addon">@</span>
            <input class="form-control" placeholder="Your email address" name="feedbackemail" id="feedbackemail" type="text" />
        </div>
    </div>
    <div class="form-group">
        <label class="control-label" for="feedbackmessage">Message</label>
        <div class="input-group">
            <textarea class="form-control" name="feedbackmessage" id="feedbackmessage" rows="8" cols="52" placeholder="The message you want to send to us."></textarea>
            <span class="form_error">Please enter your message</span>
        </div>
    </div>
    <button type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" id="feedbacksubmit_button">Submit</button>
</form>
```

The values are correctly inserted in the database, but still I get that particular error in the console saying that the submitted values were `NULL`.

**EDITED:**

By inserting breakpoints in the debugger, I get the alert box for success, while if the debugger isn't turned on, I get the alert box for error.

In both cases, the values get inserted in the database.

TABLE STRUCTURE:

```
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| Field       | Type        | Null | Key | Default | Extra          |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
| id          | int(11)     | NO   | PRI | NULL    | auto_increment |
| name        | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| email       | varchar(50) | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| message     | text        | YES  |     | NULL    |                |
| timecreated | int(11)     | NO   |     | NULL    |                |
+-------------+-------------+------+-----+---------+----------------+
```

Comment: Looks like the table column is defined as `NOT NULL`, which needs to be changed.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: It still throws an error.

Comment: Can you post the table structure in to the question. You can get it by typing `show create table feedback` in mysql terminal

Comment: Can you debug the `$values` ?

Comment: @AbdouTahiri: No. Doing an `echo($values)` shows `response=""` in javascript debugger. The values still get inserted in the database.

Comment: @AbhikChakraborty: Please see the edits in my question. I've added the table structure.

Comment: Can you paste your html code?

Comment: @DelvinPaul: I've added the HTML code in my question.

Comment: @xan: you are using $('.feedbacksubmit').click(function(). But i couldn't find any class named feedbacksubmit.

Comment: @Delvin Paul: I changed that name after trying to debug it. Edited the js function in the question above.

Answer (score 0):

First try "add" function direct from form. If it works, check the code in ajax. In this way, you can check if error is in php or ajax.